# Do I need TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE for opening hours?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, timezone

Just beforehand: This is the backend for a mobile app which is why the question about time zone arises.

I just can't get my head around this. I am having `shop_times` which are storing the information from what time of the day until another time of the day a shop has opened.

Since I want to be able to tell at which time a `shop_offer` **was** offered, I also store the interval that tells in what period this `shop_times` was or is valid. A `shop_offer` itself has a period that it is valid in. At the moment I am using `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` for all those intervals but I can't tell if I really need that.

If the user is in London and wants to see the offers and the time at which they are available, I could simply send him the date and time defined by a shop owner. I could also display this as local time so this is where I think I actually **don't** need a timezone information here.

On the other hand, without the time zone information I cannot ask "***in*** how many hours is this available" because e.g. `2016-03-22 08:00:00` is not enough to tell since the mobile user might be in a different time zone. But well, I could simply store the time zone into my `shop` entity. After all it's the location of the shop that determines the time zone. So in case a mobile user asks that question I can just send him the time zone of the shop and he can calculate the answer to this.

So.. should I store the period information **with** or **without** time zone information?

This is how my tables currently look like:

```
CREATE TABLE shop_times (

    -- PRIMARY KEY

    id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,

    shop_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_times__shop
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop(id),

    PRIMARY KEY (id, shop_id),  

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    valid_from_day TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    valid_until_day TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

    time_from TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    time_to TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

    -- CONSTRAINTS

    CHECK(valid_from_day <= valid_until_day),

    CHECK(time_from < time_to)

);


CREATE TABLE shop_offer_time_period (

    -- PRIMARY KEY 

    shop_times_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    shop_offer_id BIGINT NOT NULL,

    shop_id BIGINT NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_offer_time_period__shop_times
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_times_id, shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop_times(id, shop_id),

    CONSTRAINT fk__shop_offer_time_period__shop_offer
        FOREIGN KEY (shop_offer_id, shop_id)
        REFERENCES shop_offer(id, shop_id),

    PRIMARY KEY (shop_times_id, shop_offer_id, shop_id),

    -- ATTRIBUTES

    valid_for_days_bitmask INT NOT NULL,

    price REAL NOT NULL,

    valid_from_day TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,   
    valid_until_day TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,

);
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note:

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` **doesn't store the time zone**. It just means that Postgres applies the current `TIMEZONE` setting when (1) parsing strings (2) formatting strings (3) determining which day a time falls into, e.g. for `date_trunc` or `extract`.
- Internally, a `TIMESTAMP WITH` or `WITHOUT TIME ZONE` represents an **instant**. It is not stored as a string. The timezone only matters when you parse the store hours from user input, or when you format them to show to a shopper. No matter what timezone you're in, it's the same instant. It's just written "5pm Eastern" or "2pm Pacific".

It sounds like you need a `shops.time_zone` column and a `shopper.time_zone` column (or whatever your tables are called). That will let you parse/format these times correctly from the perspective of the user.

You *don't* need any time zone information to compute "in how many hours is this available?". That's because `NOW()` is an instant, and the offer's start time is an instant, and no matter what time zone you're in, the difference between them is always 2 hours (or whatever).

If your app is receiving timestamps from the database in JSON, then you are probably passsing them as strings. If so, I would standardize on passing them in UTC, so the app can easily interpret them and do client-side computations like "in how many hours is this available".